# Android:this is code of insert data into sqlite database having image

Tags: android

//Add Visitor details

```
btnIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //TestAdapter testAdapter=new TestAdapter(null);
                        //Cursor c=testAdapter.getData();
                          //insert Visitor name
                         String vname=edit3.getText().toString();
                        Log.w("vname", "abc");

                        /** Receiving the data from previous activity
                         **/
                        //Intent intent=getIntent();
                        //insert Visitor photo
                        Bundle gotimage1=getIntent().getExtras();
                        byte[] img1=gotimage1.getByteArray("key1");
                        Log.w("img1", "got visitor image");
                        //insert Vehicle photo
                        Bundle gotimage2=getIntent().getExtras();
                        byte[] img2=gotimage2.getByteArray("key2");
                        Log.w("img2", "got vehicle image");
                        //insert vehicle number
                        String vNo=edit1.getText().toString();
                        Log.w("vNo", "v1");
                        //insert flat number
                        String fNo=edit2.getText().toString();
                        Log.w("fNo", "f2");

                        long i=testAdapter.insertVisitorData(vname,img1 , img2, vNo, fNo);
                        //Log.e("Visitor","visitor"+vNo);
                        //Log.e("flat no","flatno"+fNo);
                        Log.e("Insertvalue","insertvalue"+i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Inserted..."+i+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

above code is to insert data having images into database using sqlite.
but unable to insert.
/********************************************
this is showing error inti logcat below:
/**********************************************

```
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.example.newandroidapp.FirstTab$4.onClick(FirstTab.java:177)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-30 14:23:59.237: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where initializing `testAdapter ` object?

Comment: i have initialized globally

Comment: Ok, what is line number 177 in FirstTab.java ?

Comment: byte[] img1=gotimage1.getByteArray("key1");

Comment: Means `gotimage1 ` is null

Comment: Move `Bundle gotimage1=getIntent().getExtras();` line in onCreate method then try to run

Comment: i am taking image in bytearray format from another activity using intent

Comment: i have tried it but not inserting value

Comment: now i am getting error at  byte[] img1=gotimage1.getByteArray("key1");